# Excel, subtotals and count/sum ifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a simple `COUNTIF` formula in Excel such as

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E,"Dave Brown",N:N,"Complete")
```

How would I amend this into a Subtotal? So far I've got this for the first part...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E:E="Dave Brown")*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(E1,ROW(E:E)-MIN(ROW(E:E)),0))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "amend this into a subtotal"?

Comment: First, I would suggest that you avoid whole column references.  Otherwise you'll find the formula very inefficient.  So try something like this --> `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(E2:E100,ROW(E2:E100)-MIN(ROW(E2:E100)),0,1)),--(E2:E100="Dave Brown"),--(N2:N100="Complete"))` .

Comment: Argh... i'm getting #NAME?

Comment: I think Domenic's formula has been corrupted in the comments - Try re-typing rather than copy and paste - it should work as written

Comment: @Domenic - do you want to post your formula as an answer - easier to copy and paste from there

Comment: @barryhoudini Yeah, I see what you mean.  Sure, I'll post the formula as an answer.  Thanks Barry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you avoid whole column references. Otherwise you'll find the formula very inefficient. So try something like this...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(E2:E100,ROW(E2:E100)-MIN(ROW(E2:E100)),0,1)),--(E2:E100="Dave Brown"),--(N2:N100="Complete"))
```

Hope this helps!